# I am getting (NSMergeConflict for NSManagedObject) when trying to delete an object

Tags: cocoa, core-data, ios4, nsmanagedobject

What can cause an error like (NSMergeConflict for NSManagedObject)? I am not using threads? I have set a MOC to handle a SQL DB via Core Data. i am trying to delete one reminder from a list of reminders. Throw that error and obviously does not remove it from the DB. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you pull the reminder out into two different managed objects and edit both ? .. It seems it is complaining that it cannot merge the data in memory for saving to the db store.